# Jquery datepicker - How do we hide the text inside a datepicker textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I have two textbox side by side. The first textbox is a regular textbox.

The second textbox is a jquery datepicker. When user selects the date in the datepicker, I add the selected value to the first textbox and I would like to hide the value of the datepickers selected date.

I below is my jquery datepicker js but is not working as expected.

```
var $dataDescriptionTextBox = $("#descriptionTextbox"); 
$(".datePickerImage").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, thisObject) {
            thisObject.input[0].value = "";
            var desc = $dataDescriptionTextBox.val();
            var newDesc = desc + dateText;
            $dataDescriptionTextBox.val(newDesc);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/D4AGz/342/

JS:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    altField: "#alt"
});
$('#datepicker').on('change', function () {
    $(this).val("");
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>Date:
    <input id="datepicker" type="text" />
    <input id="alt" type="text" />
</p>
```

Comment: I actually need to get the value of the datepicker so I can add the selected date to the first textbox. Your example replaces the values of the first textbox -not adding the values.

Comment: I changed your js code a bit to satisfy the result I wanted http://jsfiddle.net/johngarcia25/D4AGz/355/

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this:

1. Make the textcolor the same as the background color of the text box.
2. Using  onKeyPress event, after every keystroke take the value from your textbox, and append it into a hidden textbox you've got elsewhere on the page (or a javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
$(".datePickerImage").text('');
```